# Sort Date Column in jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using ASP.NET MVC with JQGrid.

The issue now is, how can I sort the `date` column in the JQGrid? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client side, you can use the sorttype and datefmt options to instruct jqGrid to sort these columns.

For example:

```
sorttype: "date", datefmt: "M d, Y at h:i"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do the sort on the DB server. I've elaborated on how I do this in [a series of blog posts](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/tag/jqgrid/), and you can download a demo solution (which doesn't use a DB, but can nevertheless sort on a date on the server side) there.